# Does background thread run on lower priority than foreground thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Does background thread run on lower priority than foreground thread even though their `Thread.Priority` is set to same value?

Consider code below: -

```
Thread threadFG = new Thread(MyMethod);//foreground thread

Thread threadBG = new Thread(MyMethod);//background thread
threadBG.IsBackground = true;
```

Will there be a difference in performance? Note that I am using default priority for both the threads.

Lot many articles on web including MSDN say that background thread will automatically destroy on application exit which is not the case with foreground thread. Lot many questions on StackOverflow say the same. But I do not found a resource that talk about performance difference between two.

Just because background thread, will that thread run slower than foreground thread?

Comment: [Foreground and Background threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0(v=vs.110).aspx): "Background threads are *identical* to foreground threads with one exception: a background thread does not keep the managed execution environment running" (My *emphasis*)

Comment: You can confirm what @Damien_The_Unbeliever has said by starting two threads, and inspecting the [Thread.Priority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does background thread run on lower priority than foreground thread even though their `Thread.Priority` is set to same value?

*No*. Unless explicitly assigned, all threads start with default priority e.g. [`Normal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Will there be a difference in performance?

*Measure it yourself*, use stopwatch or similar mechanism to measure performance. Execution performance of threads rely on many things including host computer's components (CPU architecture, number of cores etc.).

> Just because background thread, will that thread run slower than foreground thread?

*No*. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever's [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0(v=vs.110).aspx) explains: Foreground or Background has nothing to do with performance.